# Is Deep Blue superintelligent or not?

Tags: definitions, superintelligence, deep-blue

When AI has some narrow domain, such as chess, where it can outperform the world's human masters of chess, does it make it a [superintelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superintelligence) or not?

Comment: [Here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/9165/2444) is a related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three typical use cases for the phrase 'superintelligent':

1. Something that is at least as smart as a human for *every* task.
2. Something that is smart enough to improve itself on a fundamental level.
3. Something that is smarter than a human at a *single* task.

Most uses that I see are definition 2, but the other two are also somewhat common. I typically follow I. J. Good and use [ultraintelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I._J._Good#Research_and_publications) for the first definition. (There are lots of arguments that something that fits definition 1 is likely to fit definition 2 as well, but this doesn't seem to be logically necessary.)

Obviously, Deep Blue only counts for definition 3.