# Is AlphaZero an example of an AGI?

Tags: game-ai, definitions, agi, alphazero, alphago

From DeepMind's [research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01815.pdf) on arxiv.org:

> In this paper, we apply a similar but fully generic algorithm, which
>   we call *AlphaZero*, to the games of chess and shogi as well as Go,
>   without any additional domain knowledge except the rules of the game,
>   demonstrating that a general-purpose reinforcement learning algorithm
>   can achieve, tabula rasa, superhuman performance across many
>   challenging domains.

Does this mean AlphaZero is an example of AGI (Artificial General Intelligence)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good question!

- AlphaZero, though a major milestone, is most definitely *not* an AGI :)

AlphaGo, though strong at the game of Go, is *narrowly strong* ("strong-narrow AI"), defined as strength in a single problem or type of problem (such as Go and other non-chance, perfect information games.)

- AGI, at minimum, must be about as strong as humans in *all* problems worked on or solved by humans.

AGI is often associated with [superintelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superintelligence), defined as intelligence that surpasses human levels.

AGI does not necessarily imply super-intelligence, in the sense that we'd consider an android that can perform all human activities with the same capability as humans as an [Artificial General Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence).

But technically, AlphaGo is a narrow superintelligence in that it exceeds all human performance in a single problem.

Comment: I do not disagree with you, but your answer seems to be about AlphaGo Zero rather than AlphaZero, which is still narrow, but not nearly as narrow as AlphaGo.

Comment: AlphaZero domain is very narrow.  Can't read text.  Doesn't do calculus.  Can't do scrabble or jeopardy.  [AlphaTensor](https://www.deepmind.com/blog/discovering-novel-algorithms-with-alphatensor) is starting in on linear algebra, but it takes a very particular (simplified [gridworld-style](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/351026848_Reward_Shaping_Based_Federated_Reinforcement_Learning) ) game formulation.